# why does this return none value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, blackjack

I am trying to make a blackjack game

Everything works fine till the if and elif statement...

If you try this code in your code platform , you will see that in the if block 'new_user_card' is none type..

why is that?

same for the elif block

thanks in advance!

```
    import random
cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
 
def hand():
    user_cards = random.sample(cards, 2) 
    print(f"Your cards are : \n {user_cards}")
    computer_cards = random.sample(cards,1)
    print(f"Computer's first card {computer_cards}")
    more = input("Do you want to draw another card? Type 'y' for yes and 'n' for no : ")
    if more == "y":
        new_user_card = print(random.choice(cards))
        user_cards.append(new_user_card)
        print(f"Your cards are : \n {user_cards}")
    elif more == "n":
        computer_new_card = print(random.choice(cards,1))
        computer_cards.append(computer_new_card)
        print(f"Computer's has been dealt the second card.\n Computer's cards are {computer_cards}")
    return user_cards
    return computer_cards
    
hand()
```

Answer (score 1):

`print()` function returns `None`, here you have assigned the return value of `print(random.choice(cards))` to your variable.

use
`new_user_card = random.choice(cards)`
and add
`print(random.choice(cards))` on a seperate line, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `print` function, which prints to stdout, but returns None.

Just get rid of the function.

For example:

```
# this is wrong 
# new_user_card = print(random.choice(cards))
new_user_card = random.choice(cards)
```